# How to return items to a list from a list that is case-insensitive and uses a for loop and if...else statement to test for a specific fruit type

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've just started learning python and am stuck and frustrated on a practice question. For this question, I needed to create a list of fruits that will be returned to a new list as upper case if it is a berry, and the query is not case-sensitive. I can get the query to work, but it returns the two elements separately and not as a list:

```
fruit = ["coconut", "kiwi", "mango", "blueberry", "pear"] 
fruitUpper = [f.upper() for f in fruit]
for b in fruitUpper: 
  def berry():
    berry = ["strawberry", "raspberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "passionfruit"]
    for berry in berry:
      if berry.casefold() == b.casefold():
        return True
  if berry():
    print(b)
```

I also tried `print(list((b)))`, but this returned two separate lists with each letter as an element in the list. Please help!

Comment: You could probably just create a new (empty) list, and instead of printing your berries, add them to the list. At the end, if you wanted to, You could print the list of berries.

Answer (score 0):

Create another list and add the item everytime berry() is True. At the end, return the new list.

Example:

```
def isBerry(myBerry):
    berries = ["strawberry", "raspberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "passionfruit"]
    for berry in berries:
      if berry.casefold() == myBerry.casefold():
        return True
    return False

fruit = ["coconut", "kiwi", "mango", "blueberry", "pear"] 
fruitUpper = [f.upper() for f in fruit]
allBerries = []
for b in fruitUpper: 
    if isBerry(b):
        allBerries.append(b)
        
        
print(allBerries)
```

Offtopic: is there any reason why you use `f.upper()` in the berry method? You compare them by lowercasing them both. So there is no reason to first uppercase them.

Comment: I was trying to control how the elements were returned to the list (as all uppercase), but I could only get them to return as separate lines and all uppercase. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
fruit = ["coconut", "kiwi", "mango", "blueberry", "pear"] 
fruitUpper = [f.upper() for f in fruit]
berry = ["strawberry", "raspberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "passionfruit"]
result = []
for b in fruitUpper:
    for berryone in berry:
        if berryone.casefold() == b.casefold():
            result.append(b)

if result:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this as you expected:

```
# a list of fruits
fruits = ["coconut", "kiwi", "mango", "blueberry", "pear"]
berries = ["strawberry", "raspberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "passionfruit"]

#create new empty list
fruit_is_berry = []

#uses for loop
for fruit in fruits:
    # check using if else statement
    if fruit in berries:
        # if fruit is a berry, append fruit to new list wih uppercase
        fruit_is_berry.append(fruit.upper())
    else:
        print(f'{fruit} is not a berry')

# print fruit is berry new list
print(fruit_is_berry)
```

Or this (list-comprehension as in tagged):

```
fruits = ["coconut", "kiwi", "mango", "blueberry", "pear"]
berries = ["strawberry", "raspberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "passionfruit"]

fruit_is_berry = [fruit.upper() for fruit in fruits if fruit in berries]
print(fruit_is_berry)
```